# How do I combine two char's into a string in C#

Tags: c#, string, char, concatenation

How do I combine two char's into a single string?

It seems as I cannot for the life of me find out how to do it whatsoever.

Comment: How about this method?      
 `'A'.ToString() + 'B'.ToString()`      Simply use `ToString` method and then add the strings.

Comment: While jitendragarg's method works, it creates more garbage than is necessary. Two garbage strings for a single resulting string.  Fruchtzwerg's method creates a single garbage object for the resulting string.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
char[] chars = {'a', 'b'};
string s = new string(chars);
```